# In Kinect SDK v2.0 how do I map a pixel in the color image to a voxel in the depth image?

Tags: kinect

I know how to go the other way around. What I am looking for is, given a (x,y) coordinate in the pixel space (of the 1920x1080 image), how do I get the corresponding (if available) (x,y,z) (in meters) of the depth image. I realize that there are more pixels than voxels and it could be possible not to find any, but Microsoft's SDK has a *CoordinateMapper* class. This exposes the *MapColorFrameToCameraSpace* function. If I use that, I can get an array of points in the camera space (x,y,z) but I am unable to figure out how to extract the mapping for a specific pixel.

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to use

> CoordinateMapper.MapDepthFrameToColorSpace

Find the color space coordinates of all depth point.
Then, compare your pixel coordinate (x, y) with these color space coordinates. My solution is to find the closest point (might have better way), because the mapped coordinates are floats.

If you use C#, here is the code. Hope it helps!

```
private ushort GetDepthValueFromPixelPoint(KinectSensor kinectSensor, ushort[] depthData, float PixelX, float PixelY)
    {
        ushort depthValue = 0;
        if (null != depthData)
        {
            ColorSpacePoint[] depP = new ColorSpacePoint[512 * 424];

            kinectSensor.CoordinateMapper.MapDepthFrameToColorSpace(_depthData, depP);

            int depthIndex = FindClosestIndex(depP, PixelX, PixelY);

            if (depthIndex < 0)
                Console.WriteLine("-1");
            else
            {
                depthValue = _depthData[depthIndex];
                Console.WriteLine(depthValue);
            }
        }
        return depthValue;
    }

    private int FindClosestIndex(ColorSpacePoint[] depP, float PixelX, float PixelY)
    {
        int depthIndex = -1;
        float closestPoint = float.MaxValue;
        for (int j = 0; j < depP.Length; ++j)
        {
            float dis = DistanceOfTwoPoints(depP[j], PixelX, PixelY);
            if (dis < closestPoint)
            {
                closestPoint = dis;
                depthIndex = j;
            }
        }
        return depthIndex;
    }

    private float DistanceOfTwoPoints(ColorSpacePoint colorSpacePoint, float PixelX, float PixelY)
    {
        float x = colorSpacePoint.X - PixelX;
        float y = colorSpacePoint.Y - PixelY;
        return (float)Math.Sqrt(x * x + y * y);
    }
```